# nquad Integration in SciPy

Tags: scipy, integration

I am trying to self-learn SciPy and evaluate the following **quadruple** integral using [`scipy.integrate.nquad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html):

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-x} (w+y) \:dz \:dy \:dx \:dw $$

I wrote the following code:

```
from scipy import integrate

def f(z, y, x, w):
    return w + y

def bounds(z):
    return [0, 1-z]



I = integrate.nquad(f, [bounds, [0,1], [0,1], [0,1]])

                    
print(I)
```

However, it gives the following error:

```
bounds() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Any help to solve this quadruple integral is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it is the $w$ variable that has the range $[0,1-x]$

```
from  scipy.integrate import nquad

def func(w,x,y,z):
    return w+y

def range_z():
    return [0,1]

def range_y(z):
    return [0,1]

def range_x(y, z):
    return [0,1]

def range_w(x, y, z):
    return (0,1-x)

res=nquad(func, [range_w, range_x, range_y, range_z])
print(res)
```

Running it produces 0.41666666666666674 which matches the analytic answer 5/12.

Assuming it is the $z$ variable that has the range $[0,1-x]$,

```
from  scipy.integrate import nquad

def func(z,y,x,w):
    return w+y

def range_w():
    return [0,1]

def range_x(w):
    return [0,1]

def range_y(x,w):
    return [0,1]

def range_z(y,x,w):
    return (0,1-x)

res=nquad(func, [range_z, range_y, range_x, range_w])
print(res)
```

In this case the answer from the code is 0.5 which matches the analytic answer 1/2.

Comment: Actually it is the z variable that has the range [0,1−x], and the analytic solution is 0.5. Based on your answer I figured out how to get this correct value, please consider editing your answer in order to accept it as a correct one. Thank you!

Comment: @Sha Ok, added another script for the case $z \in [0,1-x]$.